# Select last not readonly input jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select the last input not having the `readonly` attribute.

I have tried `input:last:not([readonly])` and `input:not([readonly]):last` but it seems not to work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

As you reported it works to you and I tested it works on your JS Fiddle, here is the code ([JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/60x47pu1/2/)):

It is supposed to set the focus on the next input when you press enter on a input in the table, but when it is the last not readonly input, I need to set the focus on the input with the `Barcode` label.

**HTML**

```
Barcode: <input name="barcode" type="text" id="formInput_91" class="form-control" value="" autocomplete="off">

<br>
<table id="table_invoiceProducts" class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Article</th>
         <th>Descriptio</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Tax</th>
         <th>Qty</th>
         <th>Subtotal</th>
         <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" style="border: none; width: 32px;" name="product[1543338984947183200][productId]" class="adjustInputWidth input_productId" value="456" readonly=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" style="border: none; width: 40px;" name="product[1543338984947183200][description]" class="adjustInputWidth input_description" value="Test"></td>
         <td><input type="number" style="border: none; width: 58px;" name="product[1543338984947183200][price]" class="adjustInputWidth input_priceUnit" data-id="1543338984947183200" value="25.00" min="0" step="0.01"></td>
         <td><input type="number" class="adjustInputWidth input_tax" style="border: none; width: 50px;" data-id="1543338984947183200" value="0.00" name="product[1543338984947183200][tax]"></td>
         <td><input type="number" value="1" min="1" style="border: none; width: 26px;" data-id="1543338984947183200" class="input_quantity adjustInputWidth" name="product[1543338984947183200][quantity]"></td>
         <td><span style="color:#000;" class="span_priceSubTotal" data-id="1543338984947183200">25.00</span></td>
         <td><span style="color:#000;" data-id="1543338984947183200" class="span_priceTotal">25.00</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" style="border: none; width: 40px;" name="product[1543338991430875154][productId]" class="adjustInputWidth input_productId" value="1234" readonly=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" style="border: none; width: 104px;" name="product[1543338991430875154][description]" class="adjustInputWidth input_description" value="Product"></td>
         <td><input type="number" style="border: none; width: 58px;" name="product[1543338991430875154][price]" class="adjustInputWidth input_priceUnit" data-id="1543338991430875154" value="50.00" min="0" step="0.01"></td>
         <td><input type="number" class="adjustInputWidth input_tax" style="border: none; width: 50px;" data-id="1543338991430875154" value="0.00" name="product[1543338991430875154][tax]"></td>
         <td><input type="number" value="1" min="1" style="border: none; width: 26px;" data-id="1543338991430875154" class="input_quantity adjustInputWidth" name="product[1543338991430875154][quantity]" readonly=""></td>
         <td><span style="color:#000;" class="span_priceSubTotal" data-id="1543338991430875154">50.00</span></td>
         <td><span style="color:#000;" data-id="1543338991430875154" class="span_priceTotal">50.00</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#table_invoiceProducts').on('keydown', 'input:not(:last)', function(e){
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
            if(keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#table_invoiceProducts input:not([readonly])')[$('#table_invoiceProducts input:not([readonly])').index(this)+1].focus();
                $('#table_invoiceProducts input:not([readonly])')[$('#table_invoiceProducts input:not([readonly])').index(this)+1].select();
            }
        });

        $('#table_invoiceProducts').on('keydown', 'input:not([readonly]):last', function(e){
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
            if(keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13){
                e.preventDefault();
                $( '#formInput_91' ).focus();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your selector works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/v72dgx4c/. If you're having a specific problem then we need to see *all* the relevant code to reproduce it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Wou... I am going to work to post the full code

Comment: As said by @RoryMcCrossan, edit the post with the relevant JS code to see if there are any typos

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").filter(':not([readonly])').last()
```

example: https://codepen.io/filipemansano/pen/PxdmoW

Comment: I do not see the reason for the vote down, because the code informed works perfectly as the codepen example

Comment: Hi, I have not test it, and I think it may work, but I need it as a jQuery selector (upvoted you comment to delete the downvote you received).

Comment: ok no problem, i tested before post here, and works, this way is more verbose (using nested functions), like Object Orientation (more easy to understand) and this way also returns a jquery selector

Comment: I didn't downvote but the problems with this answer is that you give no explanation of why this helps or what the problem was, and it makes no logical difference to the OPs code which already works.

Comment: @FilipeMansano The problem is... how do I use it to modify my code on a way my code could start working? Look at my post, my code is there.

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping for 30 minutes, I found the solution on a beat.

As you pointed, just `input:not([readonly]):last` do the trick. So, why it didn't worked for me?

My issue was because the last not readonly input was affected by the two events posted on the question details. One that triggers when you press enter on the last not readonly and another that triggers when press enter on any not last input.

So the solution was simply selecting all the not `readonly` and change the behavior after checking if it was the last or not.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/60x47pu1/3/

Basically, I replace the JS code posted for this:

```
$('#table_invoiceProducts').on('keydown', 'input:not(:last)', function(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if(keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13){
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($('#table_invoiceProducts input:not([readonly])').length == $('#table_invoiceProducts input:not([readonly])').index(this)+1){
            $( '#formInput_91' ).focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#table_invoiceProducts input:not([readonly])')[$('#table_invoiceProducts input:not([readonly])').index(this)+1].focus();
            $('#table_invoiceProducts input:not([readonly])')[$('#table_invoiceProducts input:not([readonly])').index(this)+1].select();
        }          
    }
});
```

Offtopic: Remember to sleep well.